# Adding a value for an "if" event to a database

Tags: r

I am working for an application and a part of the data I am analyzing looks like this:

```
UserID      Date            EventId      Favorited      NumberDifferentDate    
01          01/01/2016          a            0              2
01          01/01/2016          b            1              2
01          02/01/2016          c            0              2
01          02/01/2016          d            0              2
02          03/01/2016          e            0              3
02          05/01/2016          f            0              3
02          06/01/2016          g            0              3
03          06/01/2016          g            1              1
```

So here you have three different users, user01 take his first session the 01/01/2016 and he looked at two different "event" (content in the app) and he favorited one. He also does an other session the day after but favorited no "event". 
Understanding the two other users is straightforward..

What I am trying to do is to determine if during the first session (the first date the user connect) the user favorited an event, it's going to have a positive influence on the fact that he is going to connect another time (different date).

I am familiar with linear regression so no help needed here,

My question is: How can I create a new column or a value in R that indicates me if a user favorited an event during his first session (first session only). "0" being "no" and "1" being "yes" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
df %>% left_join(
  df %>%
    group_by(UserID, Date) %>%
    summarize(sum.favorites.by.date = sum(Favorited)) %>%
    # arrange(Date) %>% # may need this, may not. Will probably only work if your date is an actual date or time type
    summarize(favorited.first.day = ifelse(first(sum.favorites.by.date), 1, 0))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Note that I modified your original data to make for a better test of effectiveness. Specifically, I added a non-first visit `Favorite` for User 2 to make sure it did not falsely label it a `First.Fav`

```
    mydat<-read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
UserID      Date            EventId      Favorited      NumberDifferentDate    
01          01/01/2016          a            0              2
01          01/01/2016          b            1              2
01          02/01/2016          c            0              2
01          02/01/2016          d            0              2
02          03/01/2016          e            0              3
02          05/01/2016          f            1              3
02          06/01/2016          g            0              3
03          06/01/2016          g            1              1")

library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

mydat$Date<-as_date(mdy(mydat$Date))
mydat<-data.table(mydat)

mydat[,First.Fav:=ifelse(Date == min(Date), 1, 0), by = c("UserID")]
mydat[,First.Fav:= ifelse(Favorited ==1 & First.Fav ==1, 1, 0), by = "UserID"]
mydat

 UserID  Date       EventId Favorited NumberDifferentDate First.Fav
 1       2016-01-01   a         0             2             0
 1       2016-01-01   b         1             2             1
 1       2016-02-01   c         0             2             0
 1       2016-02-01   d         0             2             0
 2       2016-03-01   e         0             3             0
 2       2016-05-01   f         1             3             0
 2       2016-06-01   g         0             3             0
 3       2016-06-01   g         1             1             1
```